# Animate transition on change of its absolute position's parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I have an absolute div that change it's position on user reaction.

For example:

```
//At start
.myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
}

//After change
.myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
}
```

My willing is to have its transit to the new location animated.

I'ne added [ngAnimate](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate) as a dependency and created the following class:

```
.anchor-animate.ng-enter,
.anchor-animate.ng-leave,
.anchor-animate.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition: 1s linear all;
  position:relative;
}
```

And this is the div:

```
<div class="anchor animate anchor-animate"></div>
```

But from some reason when the position change, it does not add.ng-move the element and the element does not animate, it just appears

Comment: Why not just change a class with AngularJS and let CSS do its thing? `.myDiv.moved {left: 50px;}`

Comment: because only angular know what is the value of the new "left"

Comment: Fair enough. I'm doing something similar right now with `ng-style` and `transform: translate(...)`. That's an option, too.

Comment: If you have a sample that works that's a great answer for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a left value to the directive and let CSS do the heavy lifting:

```
<div class="anchor animate anchor-animate" left="{{left}}"></div>

myApp.directive('anchor', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('click', function () {
                elem.css('left', attrs.left);
            });
        }
    }
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.left = '100px'; 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8v97d2t1/)**

You'd use a scope variable to set the value of `left`, of course.

Comment: Answer updated to use scope variable for left value.